# Magento 2 - the frontend works, but admin shows "This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect."

Tags: magento2, admin, frontend

In Magento 2, why can I go to frontend and access the pages, but not to admin. In env.php the adin url is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be causing it is your directory path. Make sure your directory path in your apache config file points to the Magento install directory

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by firewall protection or proxy network settings for web secure urls.

You can fix this issue with web secure urls in admin panel by changing `core_config_data` table field `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml` value 1 to 0.

Clean the cache and then your admin panel will work again.